# Google Generative Ai : Response status code was unacceptable: 400 Error

Tags: swift, swiftui, google-generativeai

Im new to the coding and I encountered this error while  trying to make working chatbot.

I belive code is working but the thing is it works 1,2 times and it doesnt work even no code was changed. here is the code I hope I can get help.

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleGenerativeAI

struct chatAI: View {
    
    @State var answer = ""
    @State var promptMain = "Can you hear me?"
    let palmClient = GenerativeLanguage(apiKey: ..... )
    @State var history1 = ""
    @State var errorMessage = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(history1).foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Text(answer).foregroundStyle(.white)
                }
                HStack{
                    TextField("", text: $promptMain)
                        .border(.white)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Button("ASK"){
                        Task {
                            await goNuts()
                        }
                        history1 = promptMain
                        promptMain = ""
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }.padding()
                if !errorMessage.isEmpty {
                    Text("Error: \(errorMessage)")
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func goNuts() async {
        let prompt = promptMain
        do {
            let response = try await palmClient.generateText(with: prompt)
            if let candidate = response.candidates?.first, let text = candidate.output {
                answer = text
            }
        } catch {
            
            errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe your issue in more detail? I would suggest resetting the properties answer and errorMessage before calling or at the start of the function goNuts.

Comment: When I first implanted it it worked 50/50 and then I ran the code on my phone and never worked in phone then I tried on preview and don't get any response again, I then made another app same code and I got response few times till same things happened after. I rested all the properties but I still don't get any response. I got this error : esponse status code was unacceptable 400,  I looked it up but I couldn't get any fix.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.